# How to hide .us domain information?

Tags: web-development, wordpress

I have a domain with Namecheap as .US , but recently namecheap stop supporting .us domain from who is...so now its doesn't support "whois" what else i can do for hiding my domain information?

Comment: Welcome. You got good answer and accepted it, which is is good ***BUT***, your question is badly off topic here (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ would have been better, or https://superuser.com/). I am trying to help, not criticize, bu tin future your question might be put on hold or deleted if you post on the wrong S.E site - we run a tight ship here ;-) Welcome and good luck, we hope to be of help in the future

Comment: Please proofread your question title. "Domain"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If namecheap does not support any doamin like .US then it can't be possible to add whois at this server, But its not the end of world...You can change it to other servers...such as Godaddy etc

Also make sure that the place you are switching to support's the whois for your domain!